# Dropdown Menu/Search Bar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just two small problems, working on a school assignment to recreate a generic website, using bootstrap.

A) I've been hiding a search input field/submit button in the horizontal navbar when screen is < 820px and incorporating another dropdown list named "search" with a input field in the drop down which is fine.

But I'm trying to hide this Search dropdown until screen is < 820px and targeting this list with a class and `display: none` but it's still displaying. Is there anyway you can do this?

```
<li class="dropdown searchDropDown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Search<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control searchBox" placeholder="Search">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

my `.searchDropDown {display:none}` and have a media query for max-width 820px `display: block`
But the problem is it isn't hiding this list class at full page size.

B) when i click the search dropdown and try click into the search input field but it loses focus and rolls back up.

Comment: Are you sure that your display: none property is defined under the display: block one?

Comment: It would be good to show the css you are using when asking a question about css. You can use a [JSFiddle with bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/) and put your css and html in to share with us.

Comment: could use some more info to figure out why the display: none is not working. Might be other css overwriting it, might be that your css is positioned wrong. Can't be sure

Comment: @brance i will have a quick double check now about if its defined under, I didn't think since it is only displaying in a media query defined width it would matter but i'll move it now.

Comment: @GeorgeLee 
Will post CSS in a fiddle in a sec

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2fcsgor/

For some reason also, my font color in links went back to a different color? Runs fine in chrome, but in IE + this fiddle it changes.
Forgive, completely new with this stuff.

You'll have to extend the window width so it shows. @GeorgeLee

Comment: @VladPintea jsfiddle ^^

Comment: @joshuaaron in the fiddle your markup for the search area doesn't match the one provided above.

Comment: as a side tip, if you're using plain css, try to keep media queries in one place, instead of having them duplicated. At first glance there's some duplicates and it makes the code harder to navigate, albeit not being technically incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B) your click is propagating to the above li that has a click event attached to it, you could add a function like this (jQuery)

```
$('.searchBox').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

if that doesn't work, make sure that you're actually clicking the input and not another element.

I'll get back to A in a minute

Answer (score 2):

For question A use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 820px) {
    .searchDropDown {
    display: none!important;
    }
}
```

Also, remember to close your `img` and `input` tags

Comment: Yep that will do it, how come it doesn't work without the '!important' ? thank you though

Comment: @joshuaaron it's being overridden by .nav>li, you can use your browser to inspect elements to see what css rules are getting applied to them, I use chrome as I find it easier but you can do it with any browser. To access this you can usually right click and select inspect element or press f12 :)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find that myself in the inspect elements, feel stupid. Great help though appreciated! @GeorgeLee